# every proper compact subgroup of the circle group is finite

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

let $\mathbb T$ be the circle group and $H \subsetneq \mathbb T$ be a *proper, compact subgroup*. i'm trying to show that $H$ must be finite using only topological arguments, but i'm having trouble doing so.

so i want to show that $1$ is isolated in $H$, as then $H$ is discrete and compact, hence finite. but what if $1$ happens to be a limit point of $H$? does anyone have an idea?

*background*. i'm trying to give a high level argument for why $\langle x \rangle \subseteq \mathbb T$ must be dense for all infinite order elements $x \in \mathbb T$. i'm aware of low level analysis arguments for this, but i'm not interested in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}\Pi\colon&\Bbb R&\longrightarrow&\Bbb T\\&x&\mapsto&\bigl(\cos(x),\sin(x)\bigr),\end{array}$$which is a surjective continuous group homomorphism. If $G$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb T$, $\Pi^{-1}(G)$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb R,+)$. But every subgroup of $(\Bbb R,+)$ is either dense or of the form $\Bbb Z\lambda$, for some $\lambda>0$. If $G$ is compact, then it is closed, and therefore $\Pi^{-1}(G)$ is closed too. If it happened to be dense, then it would have to be equal to $\Bbb R$. But then $G$ would be equal to $S^1$, and it is being assumed that that's not the case.  So, $\Pi^{-1}(G)=\Bbb Z\lambda$, for some $\lambda\in\Bbb R$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks. no. (1) that every additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$ is either dense or cyclic is not clear to me (and that problem seems to me quite similar to the question i asked). (2) even so, say i now have that $G$ is cyclic and compact. how can i conclude that it's finite? i still don't see it.

Comment: (1) If $H$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb R$ with $H\ne\{0\}$, take $\lambda=\inf\bigl(H\cap(0,\infty)\bigr)$. If $\lambda=0$, then $H$ is dense; otherwise, $H=\Bbb Z\lambda$. (2) If $H=\Bbb Z\lambda$ then, since $2\pi\in H$, $2\pi=n\lambda$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. And then$$\Pi(H)=\left\{(1,0),\Pi\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right),\Pi\left(\frac{4\pi}n\right),\ldots,,\Pi\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi}n\right)\right\}.$$

Comment: thanks. i see now how (2) $\Pi^{-1}(G)$ being cyclic implies that $G$ must be finite, but i still have to think about (1) a bit. it seems to me that the crux of the problem lies there (to which it's neatly reduced by what you have done).

Comment: Suppose that $\lambda=0$ and take $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$. If $a<0<b$, then $0(\in H)$ belongs to $(a,b)$. If $0<a<b$, take $h\in H\cap(0,\infty)$ with $h<b-a$. Let $n\in\Bbb N$ be the largest non-negative integer with $nh\leqslant a$. Then $(n+1)h>a$ and$$b-(n+1)h=b-nh-h\geqslant b-a-h>0.$$So, $(n+1)h\in(a,b)$.

Comment: And if $\lambda>0$, there are elements of $H$ arbitrarily close to $\lambda$ and greater than or equal to $\lambda$. If $\lambda\notin H$, take $h_1,h_2\in(\lambda,2\lambda)\cap H$, with $h_1<h_2$ than $0<h_2-h_1<\lambda$, which is impossible. So, $\lambda\in H$. Take $h\in H$. If $h\notin\Bbb Z\lambda$, take $n\in\Bbb Z$ with $n\lambda<h<(n+1)\lambda$. But then $0<h-n\lambda<\lambda$, which, again, is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If $1$ is not isolated, then there is a sequence of elements $g_i \in H\setminus\{1\}$ converging to $1$. That means $G_i = \langle n g_i \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \rangle \subset H$ because $H$ is a subgroup. Now just show that $\bigcup_{i \geq 1} G_i$ is dense in $S^1$.

Comment: how's that easier?

Comment: Let $U$ be an open subset of the circle. It contains a ball, say $[s,t]$. Just take $g_i$ so that $d(g_i,0) < |t-s|$. Then there must be an $n$ such that $ng_i \in [s,t]$. Hence $\bigcup G_i$ is dense. (Using interval notation as it's easier than working with exponentials, so I'm implicitly thinking of $S^1$ as $[0,1]/\sim$)